# AWS S3 Please reduce your request rate 200

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

What does it mean for AWS to throw the following exception with a 200 status code

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSS3IOException: copyFile(vKg4OA16S76ItqDMg-0T6A/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_202205142208258447918335555774073_0998_m_001427_2030147/part-01427-e55f193e-169b-4d1a-a009-373caa1725ab-c000.gz.parquet, vKg4OA16S76ItqDMg-0T6A/part-01427-e55f193e-169b-4d1a-a009-373caa1725ab-c000.gz.parquet) 
on vKg4OA16S76ItqDMg-0T6A/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_202205142208258447918335555774073_0998_m_001427_2030147/part-01427-e55f193e-169b-4d1a-a009-373caa1725ab-c000.gz.parquet: 
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: 
Please reduce your request rate. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 200; Error Code: SlowDown;
```

Is it some sort of warning that I'm about to hit their rate limit? I understand when the error code is 503 but when it is 200, is it safe to assume my request was completed fine?

What's the difference when the status code is 200 instead of 503 for AWSS3IOException

Answer (score 0):

According to aws docs, **A 200 response with "InternalError" or "SlowDown" is similar to a 5xx error**.
So it's not safe to assume the request was completed successfully.
You can read more about this [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-resolve-200-internalerror/) and the mechanism to avoid such situations.